# UserLocation is blowing up on "Invalid column name"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there something I missed in the setup of this model/table?

Model:

```
public class UserLocationsModel 
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

Setup:

```
public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<LocationModel> Locations { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; set; } = null!;

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserModel>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.UserID });
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserLocationsModel>()
                .HasKey(k => new { k.UserID, k.LocationID });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

This line blows up:

```
List<UserLocationsModel> locationsToRemove = userContext.UserLocations.ToList();
```

with this error:

> Invalid column name 'LocationModelID'
> Invalid column name 'UserModelUserID'

but there are no instances of either of those entities in the code.

The model is backed by this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLocations]
(
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
)
```

These are the two companion models:

```
public class LocationModel 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get => location.TrimEnd(); set => location = value; }
    public List<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; } = new();
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; } = new();
}

public class UserModel 
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; } = new();
    public List<LocationModel> Locations { get; } = new();
}
```

Comment: Check the console command if giving you the correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserLocations is a many-to-many joining table/entity. This can either be mapped directly in the relationship or indirectly where the relationships between the two entities (users and locations) are configured to use the joining table. In your case you have done both:

```
public class LocationModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get => location.TrimEnd(); set => location = value; }
    public List<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; } = new(); // <- Direct
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; } = new(); // <- Indirect
}
```

EF is going to expect two sets of joining relationships, one you have configured for, so the second it will infer from the types in question. The solution is to use one or the other.  The easiest option is the Direct relationship:

```
public class LocationModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get => location.TrimEnd(); set => location = value; }
    public List<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; } = new();
}

public class UserModel {
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<UserLocationsModel> UserLocations { get; } = new();
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you'll really only be interested in the locations for a user and/or users for a location, so to get a user's location you need:

```
 var locations = user.UserLocations.Select(ul => ul.Location).ToList();
```

This option is necessary when you have additional, meaningful properties associated to the UserLocation, such as an IsActive for soft-delete, or other properties that apply to the link between the user and location. When the table is just the UserId and LocationId then you have the option to use the indirect mapping:

```
public class LocationModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get => location.TrimEnd(); set => location = value; }
    public List<UserModel> Users { get; } = new();
}

public class UserModel {
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<LocationModel> Locations { get; } = new();
}
```

Though in this case you need to configure EF to know about the joining table when configuring the relationship. EF can infer the linking table automatically by convention which may work out fine in your case.

Comment: Removing the two references to UserLocationsModel fixed this issue.